# How to apply one to many table join and get the value in same column?

Tags: sql, db2

I have
Table A

| left | center | east |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 1 |
| 2 | Tom | 2 |

Table B

| left | top | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Red |
| 2 | Tom | Blue |

Table C

| East | west | colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Yellow |
| 2 | Tom | Orange |

i want to join table A with both the tables B and C

Expected Output

| left | center | Colour |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Red |
| 2 | Tom | Blue |
| 1 | Bob | Yellow |
| 2 | Tom | Orange |

```
Select left,center,(b.Colour,c.colour) Colour from
Table A left join Table B
On a.left = b.left
Left join Table C
On a.east=b.east
```

I want the output of colour column from table b and c in same column, how can i achieve this. I want to avoid union and union all for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH
  A (left, center, east) AS
  (
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bob', 1)
    , (2, 'Tom', 2)
  )
, B (left, top, colour) AS
  (
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bob', 'Red')
    , (2, 'Tom', 'Blue')
  )
, C (East, west, colour) AS
  (
    VALUES
      (1, 'Bob', 'Yellow')
    , (2, 'Tom', 'Orange')
  )
SELECT 
  A.LEFT, A.CENTER
, DECODE (T.NAME, 'B', B.COLOUR, C.COLOUR) AS COLOUR
FROM A
CROSS JOIN (VALUES 'B', 'C') T (NAME)
LEFT JOIN B ON B.LEFT = A.LEFT
LEFT JOIN C ON C.EAST = A.EAST
```

| LEFT | CENTER | COLOUR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | Red |
| 1 | Bob | Yellow |
| 2 | Tom | Blue |
| 2 | Tom | Orange |